# command << with bytes in java

Tags: java, byte

I am trying to understand the command "someByte << 2" in java. For what is it for? At the iscsi docmentation there is a caching mode page saying about DEMAND READ RETENTION PRIORITY and WRITE RETENTION PRIORIRY.
[image]

at the source there is this code for these messages:

```
// serialize byte 3
b = (byte)((demandReadRetentionPriority << 4) | writeRetentionPriority);
buffer.put(b);
```

Why do they use "<< 4" command with demandReadRetentionPriority and not with writeRetentionPriority? And what does << means in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the documentation that the `demandReadRetentionPriority` is in the upper 4 bits (bits 7,6,5, and 4) of the byte and `writeRetentionPriority` is stored in the lower 4 bits (3,2,1, and 0) of the byte.

The code you provided is simply shifting the value stored in the `demandReadRetentionPriority` variable to the upper 4 bits.  The `<<` is a bit shift operation.

For example, if the value of `demandReadRetentionPriority` were 1 then it would be shifted 4 bits and the byte would have a binary representation as follows:

`00010000`

And in order for one of the lower bits of `b` to be set to 1, the corresponding bit in `writeRetentionPolicy` would *have to* also be set to 1, since the lower 4 bits of `demandReadRetentionPolicy` will be 0 after the bit shift.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the "Signed left shift" operator, a bit shifting operator.

Example:

You have stored the number `279` that would be `100010111` in decimal. When you shift 4 steps to the left you get `1000101110000` (`2224`) because it will "move" the decimal number to the left and fill the spaces with zeroes.

```
   100010111 << 4
=> 1000101110000
            ++++
```

Shifting operations are very fast because they are usually implemented in the hardware as a single machine instruction.

`|` is also an operator on the bit-level: The bitwise inclusive OR.

[Summary of operators in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)